# How to fix 5xx errors for wp-content URLs in Google Search Console?

Tags: wordpress, error, crawl-errors, http-code-500

For example, the following `wp-content` URL returns an HTTP 500 status code, and Google shows a 5xx error for it in Search Console:

https://businezvalue.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/custom-css/custom-css-4.7.php

There are many other URLs like that. Day by day, the number of errors are increasing.

How can I fix these 5xx errors, and how will they affect my SEO?

Comment: A 5xx error is a very general "something went wrong" error.   There is no one-size-fits all fix to them.   Each error has some specific cause.  Without knowing what that is, we can't help you.    You need to look in your server's error log which has more detailed reasons for serving 500 errors.  If you need help solving a specific one, please edit your question with more information.